# Cannot log in to backend of a copied TYPO3 site

Tags: typo3

A copy of a TYPO3 4.4 site has been installed on a Windows 10 system. PHP and Apache versions are approximately equal. The site itself is functional and appears complete.  I can log in to the backend of the live site.  I cannot log in to the backend of the copied site.

Trials:

- Change database character set from latin1 to utf8
- Change my credentials to database credentials (username, `md5('password')`) used in `localconf.php`
- Comment out modified `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['installToolPassword']` in `localconf.php`
- `./typoconf/temp_*` deleted

#### Edit #1:

If `localconf.php` is modified to point to the live database I am able to log in. This suggests that the issue may be a difference in server versions.

#### Edit #2:

Installing MySQL server version 5.5.54 (live site has 5.5.53) makes no difference.

Comment: Do your have clear text passwords in your database?

Comment: You commented out `installToolPassword`, can you log in to install tool now with the default password `joh316`? If you, did you try to create a new admin account?

Comment: @Stony Database passwords are `md5('some_password')`, so no, the database does not have clear text passwords.

Comment: @nito Attempts to log in to the backend with `admin` or `Admin` & the default password or a modified password fail.

Comment: You log in to the backend on `yourdomain.com/typo3/` with `admin/<yourPassword>` and to `yourdomain.com/typo3/install/` with `joh316`. Commenting out `installToolPassword` has no influence on your backend login.

Comment: @nito Now you know that I'm really a noob with TYPO3! I was able to change the install tool password and log in.  Attempts to create a new admin user ran into `no default value` errors for `TSconfig` & `tx_tinyrte_tinyrte_plugins`.  Tried setting them to allow `null` values and successfully created a new user.  However, that user still cannot log in! Will try to copy those field values from a different user in a bit.

Comment: @nito Still no joy. Returning `TSconfig` & `tx_tinyrte_tinyrte_plugins` to `not null`, making a temp table with values for those fields from a different user then updating the new user did not help. There must be some other 'heavy voodoo' to quote a friend who's a graphic designer. It is also true that updating the password of an existing, legacy user did not allow logging in to backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a look a ancient history to see that one source of the error was the MySQL strict mode.  The clue that told me I was logged in was a record in the sys_log table with a current timestamp & my userid. An [old bug report](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/16450) included a comment on strict mode.  By changing MySQL 5.7 my.ini from `sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` to `sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` I gained access to my sandbox. Hooray for wayback machines everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Have you tried to set

**from:**

```
'loginSecurityLevel' => 'rsa',
```

**to:**

```
'loginSecurityLevel' => 'normal',
```

> in your localconfig.php file?

Comment: There does not exist an array key in `localconfig.php` named `loginSecurityLevel`.

Comment: Can you add that, and try again?

Comment: Adding `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['loginSecurityLevel'] = 'normal';` to `localconfig.php` makes no difference.

Comment: Can you create a new backend user into the install tool ?

Comment: As mentioned in a reply to @nito above, I was able to create a new user using the install tool, but that user is unable to log in to the backend.

Comment: If it's so then I guess the password hash is wrong. Please copy the password hash from the user which is working to the one which is not working and try to login then.
Should work ..

Comment: The hashes are identical because the local database was populated with an export of the live database via phpmyadmin.  I have also confirmed visually that they are identical.  Still does not work.

Comment: Not to copy the old password, I meant to copy the password from the user which is working on the new server, do not copy from the old database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136001/discussion-between-geob-and-elvis-tavasja).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The reason was that someone copied the system via phpmyadmin.
I copied the typo3 mysql-DB via
mysqldump ... > ...sql 
and 
mysql ... < ...sql 
and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at your cookie domain in `localconf.php`

Comment: `localconf.php` does not contain either of the words 'cookie' or 'domain'.

Comment: you can search for the cookie domain in `Install Tool > All Configuration`. Changes that you make here will then be written into the localconf.php